# Generate plot with multiple datasets in jenkins using 'Plot' plugin and multistage pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have Jankins pipeline that runs multiple tests and outputs a csv file which looks something like this:

```
name,valid,invalid,partial
a,800,500,200
b,528,0,0
c,96,25,41
d,192,0,0
e,7088,500,1200
f,288,0,0
```

and I would like to display these values in a chart resembling this picture:
[image: rough aspect of desired chart]

I do have the Plot plugin installed, but I can't make heads or tails of the documentation. It's too cryptic.

this is currently the code that I use in my Jenkins pipeline

```
 stage('Generate Charts') {
        steps {
            script {
                    sh '''
                    # this generates the csv from the output of a previous build
                    . /opt/venv/bin/activate
                    python3 ./dataset/results_parser.py ${EXPERIMENT_DATABASE_ROOT_FOLDER}/${DATABASE_NAME}/Results ${PLOT_FILE} 
                    '''
                    plot csvFileName: '${PLOT_FILE}',
                        group: 'Plot Group',
                        title: 'Regression Suite',
                        style: 'stackedBar',
                        series: [
                            [display: 'valid', yaxis: 'y1'],
                            [display: 'invalid', yaxis: 'y1'],
                            [display: 'partial', yaxis: 'y1']
                        ]
            }
        }
    }
```

but all this does is generate an empty chart:
[image: actual generated chart]

can anyone provide some pointers? I'm a bit lost width this one.

p.s. I don't necessarily want my x axis to be the build number, but having 6 separate line charts, one for each line in the csv, width the build number on the x axis would also work.